# loading error local json file after upgrade Xcode 7

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I have json file which located inside of Xcode. I was showing information to UITableView until upgrade Xcode 7. Could you please tell how to fix this issue?

Here is a sample content of json file;

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScN4a.png)

```
[
{
“title”: “School”,
“name”: [“Kyle”, “Joy”, “Melissa”],
},
{
“title”: “Job”,
“name”: [“Michael”, “Eric”, “Nichol”]
}

]
```

[and here is how i could load data before upgrade Xcode;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT2OO.png)

```
lazy var stories : [AnyObject] = {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Stories", ofType: "json")
        let data = NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

        let result = data?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let json : [AnyObject]! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! [AnyObject]

        return json
    }()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is because of NSAppTransportsecurity so you need to add the following to your project in xcode7. In Info.plist add `NSAppTransportSecurity As Dictionary` & child as `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads As Boolean` value to be YES

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but no chance, here is the error detail; fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed array around character 314671." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed array around character 314671.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 50
error line; let json : [AnyObject]! = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! [AnyObject]
What should I do?

Comment: have you followed try and catch in your project ??